Who wrote The Cleaners and what is the book about?
In Chernobyl Prayer (or Voices from Chernobyl), one of the persons interviewed by Svetlana Alexievich says,

As a boy, I read a marvellous book called The Cleaners — I've forgotten who wrote it — where they went off catching saboteurs and spies.

(Chernobyl Prayer, translated by Anna Gunin and Arch Tait. Penguin, 2016. Page 122.)
I have not been able to identify the book via Wikipedia, but I strongly suspect that the book was in Russian (rather than a translation) and that the activities referred to take place during World War II in Russia. I assume the latter because many people interviewed by Alexievich make comparisons between events after the Chernobyl disaster and World War II. (See also the term Great Patriotic War. Patriotism is also an important concept for the clean-up workers after the Chernobyl disaster.)
Of course, I could be completely wrong. I would appreciate it if someone identified the author and the historical and geographic context of the book's story.

in Ru text of this Svetlana Alexievich's book it's "Чистильщики" but that's all I can add to the question

maybe it's "В августе сорок четвёртого" (a different title) by Владимир Богомолов, from https://zabrab75.ru/articles/obshhestvo/chistilshhik-fedotov/

I believe Andra is correct, and it is Vladimir Bogomolov’s The Moment of Truth (In August of 1944).
The USSR had a legal deposit system. Several copies of every publication in the country were sent to the important libraries, such as the V. I. Lenin State Library of the USSR (today Russian State Library) or the State Public Library (National Library of Russia). However, searching for “Чистильщики” in their online catalogues doesn’t bring back any satisfying results. My further attempts at web search (including in other major libraries) were similarly unsuccessful. RSL hasn’t digitize all of its catalogues, but still this suggests that such a title does not exist.
In August of 1944 suits the description well. This book covers the events of World War II in the so called Western Belorussia. It was published in 1974 which fits the timeframe (the interviewee was a young man during Chernobyl events). There is an account of it being popular among high schoolers (while not a kids book itself). The main characters are indeed referred to as cleaners. The term was uncommon enough to demand an explanatory note:

Cleaner (from "clean" – to clear the areas of the front line and
operational rear from enemy agents) is a slang term for a military
counterintelligence investigator.

In other words, these are SMERSH operatives who work to eliminate “suspected marauders and saboteurs”.
